# remove hidden field on submit 2nd button via js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetime

it's possible remove the part of code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="alt_date" name="selArrivalDate" value='<?php $datetime = new DateTime('tomorrow'); echo $datetime->format('Ymd'); ?>' />
```

on submit Button `#bookingSubmitBtn2`?

The form here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $("#bookingSubmitBtn").click(function() {
        if ($("#children").val() == "") {
            $("#children").remove();
        }
        $("#bookingForm").submit();
    });
});
```

```html
<form name="buchenForm" id="bookingForm" method="get" action="searchresult1.php">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" value='<?php $datetime = new DateTime('tomorrow'); echo $datetime->format('d/m/Y'); ?>' class="form-control" />
        <input type="hidden" id="alt_date" name="selArrivalDate" value='<?php $datetime = new DateTime('tomorrow'); echo $datetime->format('Ymd'); ?>' />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" id="bookingSubmitBtn1" formaction="searchresult1.php">Search 1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" id="bookingSubmitBtn2" formaction="searchresult2.php">Search 2</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [DEMO LINK HERE https://jsfiddle.net/e6u6ytm3/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/e6u6ytm3/1/)

HTML

```
<form name="buchenForm" id="bookingForm" method="get" action="searchresult1.php">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" value="<?php $datetime = new DateTime('tomorrow'); echo $datetime->format('d/m/Y'); ?>" class="form-control" />
        <input type="hidden" id="alt_date" name="selArrivalDate" value="<?php $datetime = new DateTime('tomorrow'); echo $datetime->format('Ymd'); ?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button  id="bookingSubmitBtn1" formaction="searchresult1.php">Search 1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button  id="bookingSubmitBtn2" formaction="searchresult2.php">Search 2</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function() {      
        $("#bookingSubmitBtn2").click(function() {
            var hiddenElement = $('#bookingForm').find('input[name="selArrivalDate"]');
          console.log(hiddenElement);
            if (hiddenElement) {
                $(hiddenElement).remove();
            }       
            $("#bookingForm").submit();
        });
    });
```

Comment: I am sorry. Can you please explain what is the error or problem ?

Comment: Yes.
In id="bookingSubmitBtn1" button do I convert fomat 'd/m/y' to 'Ymd' , while in the case of id="bookingSubmitBtn2" date format button must remain unchanged (d/m/Y).
Thank you!

Comment: Actually your question is about remove the hidden input filed. and i guess its removing the input field.